# How do i set a specific value of an array of an array of arrays within the state

Tags: reactjs, state

In the following code, editableRowData an array containing an IComponent[] object (components):

```
deleteComponent(index) {
 ...
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            editableRowData: {
                ...this.state.editableRowData,
                //change specific component's "show" value
                components: this.state.editableRowData.components
            },
            deletedComponentIds: [...this.state.deletedComponentIds, this.state.rowData.components[index].id]
        }));
    }
}
```

IComponent[] is an object which looks like this:

```
    id: number,
    name: string,
    url: string,
    type: string,
    show: number
}
```

`editableRowData` is an array of objects containing these objects. Within the first code snippet, I want to change a component's show value to 0. What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: Do you want change `components` state object to `0` based on some condition?

Comment: @frishi no, the point of the delete function is to unconditionally change the value to 0.

Comment: You can simply set `show` to `0` in `setState`

Comment: @frishi would you mind showing how to do this with maybe a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an initial `default` state variable `show` set to some sensible default, you can explicitly set its value to 0.

So, assuming you had:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const [show, setShow] = useState(1) // 1: show, 0: hide

const deleteComponent = () => {
  setShow(0);
}

// elsewhere

{ show && <ComponentToShowHide> }
```

showing/hiding is pretty straightforward. Note that I am using the `useState` hook. I don't know if you are able to leverage it, but I do highly recommend that you use it.

Comment: what i want to know is how can i set the specific value of a component which is an object contained in editableRowData which i showed in the post's first code snippet, preferably within that code snippet.